# Why can't I swap the memory address of two variables?

Tags: c

I want to swap the memory address of two variables, like this:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
int temp;
temp = &a;
&a = &b;
&b = temp;
}
```

But the compiler doesn't allow it. Is there any good reason why this is not allowed?

I know that variables are just names representing memory locations. When you access a variable you're just accessing a memory location, so why can't you just swap the names for memory locations? In C# you can swap object names in this way so why can't you do that in C?

Is there something in the C standard that prohibits two variable names from pointing to the same address?

Comment: The memory adresses are a "real" thing but the name of variables are not.

Comment: you're just changing names, so why is it a big deal?

Comment: What could it possibly mean to swap the addresses of two objects? It doesn't make sense, hence the language doesn't allow it.

Comment: An address is where a variable *is*. You can't change that. You can make another variable elsewhere with the same value, but the original variable is where it is. Its address is not a mutable property.

Comment: It's `int main(void)`, not `void main()`.

Comment: It's for the same reason you can't change the address that you currently live at. Sure, you can tear down the house and build a new one, but you can't change the number that has been assigned to that plot of land.

Comment: okay but why can't you have two names that point to the same address then?

Comment: Why can't you swap the numbers 1 and 2 by writing: `tmp = 1; 1 = 2; 2 = tmp;`?

Comment: because 1 and 2 represent real binary values whereas a and b represent arbitrarily assigned memory locations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, you would do this with pointers:

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *temp;

*a = 5;
*b = 10;
temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

This is similar to what is actually happening when you do the same thing in C#, except C# doesn't expose the pointer syntax like C does.

Comment: Is there something in the C standard that prohibits two variable names from pointing to the same address?

Comment: No, not at all. In fact, that's what `temp = a;` does, it makes `temp` point to the same place `a` does.

Comment: Two pointers can point to the same address. Two objects cannot have the same address. Thus `p==q` can be true, but `&x==&y` can never be true.

Comment: So does C mandate a 1-to-1 bijection between variable names and objects then? That once a variable is initialized, its memory address cannot change

Comment: @user2108462: No, because objects might exist on the heap and not have a specific name (consider an element of an array), or multiple pointers might point to the same object.

Comment: @GregHewgill I was referring to the fact that the pointers themselves must refer to different memory locations. Why must &a != &b hold true for all variables? Is this specified in the C standard or is it due to compiler implementations?

Comment: In C, whenever you declare a new variable, the compiler allocates a new location in memory for that variable. However, keep in mind that a declaration such as `int a;` is *not* a pointer. (It should be noted that in C++, `&x==&y` *can* be true because of other C++ features, but the general statement for C above still holds.)

Comment: Thanks Greg, I understand that now but, why does the compiler create a static, unchanging map? Is it out of necessity, as in, there is no other possible way to compile code, or is it because the standard says the map must be static?

Comment: I can't imagine what the alternative to a static, unchanging map would be. If I give a name to a memory location (which is what a declaration does), then I don't expect that name to suddenly refer to a different memory location. Unless I were using pointers, of course, then that's exactly what I might want to do.

Comment: @user2108462: it's not stated *explicitly* in the standard, but it is pretty much a consequence of how identifiers are handled. The result is that there is a one-to-one mapping between *objects* (the thing taking up memory) and identifiers.  The language simply doesn't define a mechanism by which two separate identifiers map to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

In the C language, names disappear at translation time. (In typical C implementations, names are only ever retained at run time for features like symbolic debugging, or possibly dynamic linkage of shared libraries.)

Names are not run-time entities that can be manipulated by the program.  Even if you somehow have access to a symbol table at run time (via some compiler or library extension), which allows you not only to access a symbol like `b`, but also change the entry to make it have a different value, such a change will not propagate back to the compiled program, in which `b` no longer exists, because it has been replaced by machine language instructions which access that memory location numerically, rather than symbolically.  Symbolic changes in a C program generally require the program source code to be recompiled.

Lastly, your program is simply not valid C because in the expression:

```
temp = &a;
```

the left hand side of the assignment, `temp`, has type `int`, whereas `&a` has type `int *`. You're assigning a pointer value to an integer.

The syntax you're trying to use to denote name manipulation simply does not denote name manipulation; it denotes something else: the conversion of a pointer to an integer.

Without a cast operator, that conversion requires a diagnostic.  With a cast operator, it produces an implementation-defined integer value.

Programming languages are not like human languages; the machine has no intuition about what you really mean.  Your program isn't being rejected on the grounds that the machine understands what you really mean, but on a completely different interpretation of your intent according to the real rules of the language.

In other words, your program does not show that C doesn't support symbolic manipulation at run time, because your program does not in any way encode the request for such a thing.

What shows that C doesn't support symbolic manipulation at run time that is the lack of any description in the ISO C standard of such a feature. This means that if such a feature exists, it's only as a local extension of the particular C dialect that your compiler understands. In that case, you can find it documented in the manual for your compiler, and that documentation will show you the proper syntax.

Comment: so a variable is like a constant in that it's only allowed to have one memory address that's not allowed to change? But it's different from a constant in that two variables are not allowed to have the same memory address?

Comment: @user2108462 Only a static variable is like that. Automatic variables are multiply instantiated; they have multiple addresses at run time, possibly at the same time. (For instance, consider recursive functions which have arguments and local variables: each recursive instance has its own separate variables, but in the program text, they are declared only in one place.) But within a given scope, the address of an automatic local variable is fixed.

Comment: Different variables can not only have the same address, they can also have no address at all. This is due to optimization. Variables that cannot be optimized, and must have a storage address, will generally never overlap. This is under the control of the compiler, and standard C provides no way to request an overlapping allocation of distinct variables. For static variables, some compilers offer extensions for this: ways to tell the assembler or linker that two or more names are aliases for the same location.

Comment: Okay, so as far as I understand it, some kind of static map is created as soon as a variable is initialized that then doesn't change? Is this implementation specific or does the C standard say that each variable within a scope cannot refer to a different memory address?

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
&a = &b;
```

Is attempting to change the address  of the variable a.  This simply not allowed in C.  The same goes for:

```
&b = temp;
```

Rather, to swap the values, do the following:

```
 temp=a;
 a=b;
 b=temp;
```

---

Another approach would be to declare a and b as pointers.  Then you could swap where each points:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;

int *ap = &a;
int *bp = &b;
int *temp;

temp = ap;
ap = bp;
bp = temp;

printf("*ap[%d]\n", *ap);   // output: '*ap[10]'
printf("*bp[%d]\n", *bp);   // output: '*bp[5]'
```

Comment: I think that just changes the values of a and b and not their addresses

Comment: @user2108462, Added a bit more to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to read section 6.2.4 of the latest [C language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Note that you can have multiple *pointers* that resolve to the same address:

```
int a;
int *p = &a;
int *q = &a;
int *r = p;
```

Under this scenario, the *expressions* `a`, `*p`, `*q`, and `*r` all resolve to the same memory location, so

```
a = 1;
```

has the same effect as

```
*p = 1;
```

which has the same effect as

```
*q = 1;
```

which has the same effect as

```
*r = 1;
```

You can't update the result of `&a` because the operation is nonsensical (it's equivalent to writing something like `1 = 2`).